# Is it possible to pay ICO consultants in the ICO's new currency?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ico, smartcontracts

I am working as a consultant on a new ETH based ICO campaign.

The arrangement is that they will pay me with their new tokens they are issuing through their ICO. The problem is, as far as I know, tokens are automatically paid through a smart contract to investors based on their ETH contribution.

I am wondering if there is anyway I can guarantee receiving the tokens? I have had to turn to stack overflow to get an answer, it is incredibly difficult to find relevant, reliable information online.

Are they able to transfer their tokens prior to their ICO to an ether wallet?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It might be ok on the workspace stack exchange

Comment: Is it possible to just get a quick answer? I will make sure to use workspace in the future

Comment: that is not the way Stack Overflow works. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are able to programmatically allocate tokens to individuals without having them contribute ETH to a smart contract. You can guarantee payment by verifying they have allocated their token to your ERC-20 compliant address in their ICO contract.

They would be able to assuming their ICO contract is already deployed and has your wallet address.